# SQL Server join error

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting an error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4

while trying to retrieve the below code

```
Select *
from cds..filing 
Join fundb..Issuer on a.issuerid = b.Issuerid
where issuerid = '41266'
```

Comment: Replace double dots with single dot (e.g. `cds.filing` and `fundb.issuer`)

Comment: That error message is for SQL-Server, not MySQL. Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: You should really post the **whole error message** (the actual **error message**, too!) - not just the message number ......

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *
from cds..filing a
Join fundb..Issuer b
on a.issuerid = b.Issuerid
where a.issuerid = '41266' -- trick is here, you need to specify 'a' or 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Select *
from cds a 
inner Join fundb b
on a.issuerid = b.Issuerid
where a.issuerid = '41266'
```

you can change it to `left join` or `right join`.. it all depends on your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for inner join:

`select *
from cds a, fundb b 
where a.issuerid = b.issuerid 
and a.issuerid='41266'`

Comment: Never suggest the use of implict joins. They are a SQL Antipattern.